# Unable to load C++ DLL in C# application in Windows 7 32 bit OS

Tags: c#, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit

I have a DLL written in C++ that needs to be used by an application in C#. 
Settings: 
OS: Win7 32 OS
C++ DLL: 64 bit
C# application: 64

I set the Platform as 64 bit for C++ project. then i created the DLL.
If i try to access the C++ dll, it fails. 
getting error "Invalid DLL"

Comment: could you write the code you use for declare the external function ?

Comment: "OS: Win7 32" - You cannot load 64bit DLLs on a 32bit Operation-System.

Comment: @Felice: I refered the External function, just like a another c# class library. Previously it was working fine with 32 bit C++ dll. I added a reference and Using the assembly. i created the instance for the class and accessing. Now i changed the C++ project platform to 64 bit, now i got reference missing error.

Comment: @Lakshmanan I just see now: look at @winSharp93 comment :)

Comment: @Felice   Instead of Load, is there any other way to refer?

Comment: @Lakshmanan as @winSharp93 said, you cannot run a 64 bit dll on a 32 bit os...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is exactly as winSharp93 said.  If the DLL is 64-bit, you can't load it on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: Instead of Load, is there any other way to refer?

Comment: It's a C++ DLL compiled for a 64-bit platform: it will not work, run or be usable on a 32-bit platform.